# Deploying NodeJS to Azure fails with the 'Time' module. Anyone know why?

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying my node.js app to Azure via Dropbox. It has worked fine in the past, but after a few updates, I'm getting a "Deploy Failed" with the log errors below.

There seems to be a problem building the Node time module. I don't remember installing it, but I'm assuming it came in when I installed the 'moment' module.

Any ideas what's keeping this from building properly?

Many thanks!

```
Selected node.js version 0.8.19. Use package.json file to choose a different version.          
time@0.9.2 install C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mrtbrls-api\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\time 
node-gyp rebuild
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mrtbrls-api\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\time>node    
"D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-         gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
gypnpm ERR! time@0.9.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1

An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the time@0.9.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the time package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls time
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.8.19\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files  (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mrtbrls-api\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message time@0.9.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, so I'm leaving the answer here for the next person to come along with this problem. **The package.json file did not include this dependency**:

```
"dependencies": {
  "connect": "~2.7.4",
  "express": "~3.1.1",
  "node-uuid": "~1.4.0",
  "nodemon": "~0.7.6",
  "request": "~2.16.6",
  "shortid": "~1.0.9",
  "moment": "~2.0.0",
  "underscore": "~1.4.4",
  "cron": "~1.0.1",
  "time": "~0.9.2"
},
```

I think it would have hit some other errors if it could have made it past the time error, as there were some other dependencies missing.